# how validate nested attributes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have one form that creates a new property with the address nested. The problem is that there is no validation performed to 'address' when I leave all the form empty. It is like the system never reads the address model validation and I can even create a new property without filling the address.

I have the following models:

property.rb:

```
class Property < ApplicationRecord
 has_one :address
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :address
end
```

address.rb:

```
class Address < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :property
  validates :state, :city, presence: true
end
```

property_controller.rb:

```
  def new
    @property = Property.new
    @property.build_address
  end

  def create
    @property = current_user.properties.build(property_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @property.save
        format.html { redirect_to @property, notice: 'Property was successfully created.' }
      else
        format.html {
             @property.build_address #nedded to show the address inputs again
             render :new }
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: You can add a `'disabled'` HTML attribute to your address fields in the form. And for the model, you can try with `validates :address, presence: true`, but I have to say that I haven't tried that, yet.

Comment: Thank for your answer and it didn't change the result but could change in another way

Answer (score 0):

Inspecting the code carefully I found out that everything works good if I send at least one parameter as the nested form (ex: city) and remove the `@property.build_address` from the `create` action.